# geckodriver - cannot create a js variable then read it?

Tags: c#, selenium, geckodriver

I'm using geckodriver.exe for some Selenium automation with Firefox.  There are times when I need to make a global variable using ExecuteScript, then read that variable later on:

```
driver.ExecuteScript("  x = 'test'; ");
var result = driver.ExecuteScript("  return x; ");
```

In ChromeDriver I get a result back and it is "test" as expected.

With  GeckoDriver I get null on that second call.  Is there something I am doing wrong?  I really do intend to create a global variable here!

Comment: I wonder if `driver.ExecuteScript("window.x = 'test'; ");` would work. Any `window.x` property assignment is an implicitly declared global variable. I forgot how fun JavaScript is!

Comment: Which version of GeckoDriver are you using, and which version of Firefox are you automating?

Comment: I think you create your own scope when using ExecuteScript... it should return a promise.    I'm surprised the 2nd ExecuteScript call works in Chrome.   (If both lines were in 1 call, it'd be fine, but sort of useless) An alternative might be to create a cookie or use local storage... that would be more persistent as well.

Comment: @GregBurghardt yes that workaround fixed things. I used top.x rather than window.x, but the idea is the same. And it seamlessly works in Chrome as well.  Can you post an answer so I can choose it please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does seem a little odd that your solution didn't work. Your can leverage a quirk with Javascript where setting a property on a window object creates an [implicitly declared global variable](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/beware-of-unsafe-implicit-globals-in-javascript-f370ccca8fdb):

```
var js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;

js.ExecuteScript("window.x = 'test';");
```

When dealing with a `<frameset>` or `<iframe>` you can reference `top` to set a global variable in the top level window object:

```
js.ExecuteScript("top.x = 'test';");
```

My guess is the code you tried was setting a global variable, just not on the window object you thought.